# Не запускается Windows

Tags: windows

Случайно удалил файл в томе "Зарезервировано системой", после чего при выборе винды при включении комп просто перезапускается. Биос перестал воспринимать жесткий диск. Он его видит, но с него грузиться не хочет. Винт сата рейд wd800aajs-00psa0. Как теперь можно востановить его? Переустановка винды не помогает. При первой же перезагрузке во время установки комп вылетает.

Comment: Какая венда-то?[Восстановление совместной загрузки Windows 7 и Windows XP при переустановке одной из них](http://www.oszone.net/10377/Multiboot_XP_7)

Answer (score 1):

Загрузиться с LIVE CD, запустить с него восстановление системы, нажать R, войти в консольный режим- набрать команду fixmbr, fixboot. перезагрузиться. Это если удалили загрузчик, если не получится опять же грузиться с LIVE CD, и попробовать восстановить систему, ну и крайний случай- переустановка

Answer (score 0):

Восстановить загрузчик Windows 7 (думаю у вас она) можно встроенными средствами Windows. Вам понадобится ваш установочный диск. Включите в БИОСе загрузку с CD/DVD. При загрузке установщика сделайте так как описано в этой статье [oszone.net](http://www.oszone.net/11294/).